# Turning off vs idling?

Tags: idle

Which would cause more wear and tear on a vehicle, turning off and on multiple ~7-10 times a day or idling for 10-20 mins ~7-10 times a day? I use my personal vehicle for work and I'm trying to do what's best for my car in the long run.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: It should be obvious which is best for your bank balance, in terms of wasting fuel! Starting a hot engine 7 to 10 times a day is nothing. Modern cars which automatically switch off the engine to save fuel when you stop in traffic, and restart it when you depress the clutch pedal to engage a gear, will do far more "hot starts" than that in an hour, in stop-start city traffic.

Answer (score 2):

A typical car has the components to withstand at least 3 cold starts per day for 20 years or more. A warm start where the engine is already at the operating temperature puts far less stress on the components than a genuine cold start. So, it should definitely withstand 1 cold start and 6-9 warm starts per day.

Idling consumes about 0.5-1 litre per hour depending on the engine size. A quarter hour is between 1/8 - 1/4 litre, or where I live, about 0.25-0.5 United states dollars.

If you do this idling 10 times, quarter hour at a time, every day, you have consumed $900-$1800 worth of fuel per year. In 20 years, it's $18000-$36000.

I can definitely say that replacement of a failed starter motor will not be anywhere close to $18000-$36000. The same is true for replacement of a failed battery. The starter motor and battery are the components that will take the majority of the stress.

A start/stop-equipped car that may stop and warm-start the engine tens of times per day when stopped at traffic, uses exactly the same kind of engine that is used by non-start/stop cars. The only differences between start/stop-equipped car and normal car are (1) beefier battery and (2) beefier starter motor. So if you're worried that you can destroy an engine by starting 7-10 times per day, which would cost easily over $5000 to repair (still cheaper than the cost of fuel), the answer is that you won't destroy an engine.

There are areas (such as United States) where fuel costs are about half of the cost where I live, but even that half cost of fuel (without heavy taxation) would be $9000-$18000 per 20 years depending on the engine size.

So, I would say **no matter where you live, turn off the engine when you park for long amounts of time** -- the additional very minor damage to car components is much cheaper than the fuel consumed.

Besides, an energy-efficient gasoline engine in its lifetime will burn about 20000 litres (about $20000-$40000 USD depending on the area where you live) of fuel until it's scrapped; a big V8 could consume 40000 litres (about $40000-$80000 USD depending on the area where you live). By idling, you are putting nearly that amount of fuel through the engine just at idle. I believe the idling will cause some wear on the engine actually, wear that wouldn't happen if you properly turned the engine off.

Comment: Not asked in the question and not answered in this quite well phrased answer is the impact of all the idling on polluting the environment!

Comment: @fred_dot_u wasn’t there some research that showed emissions due to stop / start were significant cf. running...

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found from the guy I pretty much trust:
https://youtu.be/dFImHhNwbJo